# How do you clone/copy a DOM node's shadow Dom?

Tags: javascript, polymer, vaadin, shadow-dom

I am trying to clone a table row with web API's `cloneNode()` method. Inside those table rows are table data with some vaadin web components that use shadow DOM to get and render its data.

When using `cloneNode()` to do this, the shadow DOM is not cloned/copied, so now I am left with some vaadin combo-boxes that have no output when rendered.

Is there some way to overcome this?

Example of a table cell that was cloned using `cloneNode()`:

```
<td style="text-align:center;">
   <vaadin-combo-box id="xxxlist" 
    value="{{definition.lkp_xxx_unit_id}}"
    item-label-path="value" item-value-path="id">
   </vaadin-combo-box>
</td>
```

Then after that I have this block of code to actually get the items for the `vaadin-combo-box` component:

```
ready: function() {
        app.addEventListener('xxx-choices-changed', function(event) {
          this.$.xxxlist.items = app.choices['lkp_xxx_id'];
        }.bind(this));
        this.$.xxxlist.items = app.choices['lkp_xxx_id'];
      }
```

Any idea how to clone the node with the shadow DOM attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not clone the shadow dom contents. The web component (`<vaadin-combo-box>` in this case) is responsible for creating that with JavaScript when a new instance of that element is created. So, when you clone a web component and attach it to the DOM, it’ll create the shadow DOM by itself.

Your problem here is probably that the `items` property is not set for the cloned elements. Note, that the `ready` method is only run for the first instance of a Polymer web component, not for all instances. Use `connectedCallback` or `constructor` instead if you want to run some code for every instance.

Comment: This is exactly what I did to solve the problem, I reassigned all my vaadin components the items property, and it resolved the problem.

Answer (score -4):

If you want to clone a node and it´s children you have to tell [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) so. Please try setting the deep param of cloneNode to true.

```
element.cloneNode(true);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! I did set that to true, but It didn't get anything under the shadowRoot of the DOM node that I cloned.

Comment: Agreed.  This would be a feature that would be nice without having to do any crazy recursive insanity.  A built-in feature to clone an entire DOM or DOM structure would be nice.